# One Webjob or several

Tags: design, azure

I am writing a web Job that will process messages from Azure Topic Subscriptions.

Each message received by the Topic may need additional processing and the Topic Subscription Filters will contain the logic to determine this. The messages that are placed in to a Subscription will then be processed by the Web Job.

I am unsure which is the best architecture:

a) One Web Job for the Topic, with multiple methods that are each triggered by messages appearing in an associated subscription?

b) A separate Web Job per Subscription?

Any advice for the best design would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that it is better to add a single WebJob per Topic and have individual classes that handle each subscription.

This gives a self contained application, that find a balance between ease of maintenance and ease to update and deploy.